# Taking the limit of an integral

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I have:
$$\lim_{x\uparrow a} \int ^{g(x)}_{h(x)}f(x,y)dy $$

$f(x,y)$, $g(x)$, $h(x)$, are all continuous from below in $x$ at $a$, and $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $y$.

Is there any way to solve this? Is there a move available like:

$$\lim_{x\uparrow a} \int ^{g(x)}_{h(x)}f(x,y)dy = \int^{\lim_{x\uparrow a}g(x)}_{\lim_{x\uparrow a}h(x)}\lim_{x\uparrow a}f(x,y)dy $$

That would be nice. Thanks in advance for help.

EDIT: Or, if such a move is not *generally* possible/this limit not generally solvable, are there restrictions I could place on the functions which make it so?

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\uparrow a} \int ^{g(x)}_{h(x)}f(x,y)\,dy=\lim_{x\uparrow a}F\big(x,g(x)\big)-F\big(x,h(x)\big)=F\big(a,g(a)\big)-F\big(a,h(a)\big)$$=\int ^{g(a)}_{h(a)}f(a,y)\,dy.$

Where $F(x,y)=\int ^{g(x)}_{h(x)}f(x,y)\,dy.$

Comment: Thanks for your help - but did you mean to make $F(x,y)$ a definite integral?